# For b1/b2 visa is it okay to change my actual travel itinerary from original travel plans I outlined in DS 160 form?

Tags: b1-b2-visas

I received the b1/b2 visa, and I want to travel to US. According to my original travel plans I gave only 10 days for my travel while applying for the visa in DS160 form but now I want to stay around 50 days to extend my time in US for some tourism and follow up meeting purposes.

Also I want to change my hotel (the place where you stay in US given in DS 160 form) since I found a cheaper and convenient one.

Since it is my first time travel I am a little worried about these changes as these are not in align with my original travel plans outlined in DS 160.

Is it okay to go ahead with the new plan or should I strictly book my flight and hotel according to DS 160 I applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you received the B1/B2 visa, you can travel to the US at any time during its validity period for any purpose permitted by the visa (e.g. tourism and business). It does not have to be your original declared travel plans. It is very common for plans to change and this is not a problem.

Comment: @Jab2Tech you should meantioned to the Immigration Officer your changed travel plans upon entry.